# Zoom in on AppBarLayout on overscroll downwards

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I've been struggling for quite some time to achieve a zoom effect on AppBarLayout when pulling down anywhere on the page (overscroll).

Example of desired effect:
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4443

My layout has the following layout (removed irrelevant views):

```
--CoordinatorLayout
    -- AppBarLayout
        -- CollapsingToolbarLayout
             --FrameLayout
                 --ImageView
    -- NestedScrollView
        -- ...
```

I've managed to get somewhat close to the desired behavior when overscrolling the NestedScrollView (with help from [this](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/overscroll-appbarlayout-behavior-e58f1ee2807#.7fjf1nz2b)) but I've had no luck triggering the behavior when overscrolling on the AppBarLayout.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar requirement and modified one of the publicly available view behavior to suite my needs.

You can use the same and modify it as per your needs. The behavior is available [Here - gist](https://gist.github.com/trivalent/593a9d5552c9fd6cb35b7085b2005928)